# If $u(x)\leq\int\limits_{x_0}^xa(t)u(t)dt$ for any $x\geq x_0 $ then $u(x)=0$ for any $x\geq x_0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that the functions $a(x)\geq0$, and $u(x)\geq0$ are continuous for $x\geq x_0$. Show that

1. If $u(x)\leq\int\limits_{x_0}^xa(t)u(t)dt$ for any $x\geq x_0 $ then $u(x)=0$ for any $x\geq x_0$
2. If $u(x)\leq\int\limits_{x_0}^xa(t)u^2(t)dt$ for any $x\geq x_0 $ then $u(x)=0$ for any $x\geq x_0$

**My atttempt for part 1:**

Let $G(x)=\int\limits_{x_0}^xa(t)u(t)dt$
Then $u(x)\leq G(x)$

And
$G^{'}(x)=a(x)u(x)$

Hence
$\frac{G^{'}(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{a(x)u(x)}{G(x)}\leq a(x)$

Thus
$\int\limits_{x_0}^x\frac{G^{'}(t)}{G(t)}dt\leq \int\limits_{x_0}^xa(t)dt$

Which gives
$G(x)\leq G(x_0)e^{\int\limits_{x_0}^xa(t)dt}$

And with the way we have defined $G(x)$ we can see $G(x_0)=0$.
So, $G(x)\leq0$

Therefore
$0\leq u(x)\leq G(x)\leq0$
That is $u(x)=0$

But I don't feel confident with the method I used above.
Appreciate your opinion (May be there is a different approach..)

Also how about the part two? Should I have to use the exact same method ?

Comment: You are on the right track. Part a by the way, is a special case. Of Grownwall’s inequality.

Comment: You put $G(x)$ in the denominator, but how do you know $G(x)\neq 0$?  There is a simple fix, but I'll leave you to try to figure it out for now.

Comment: So for $G(x)=0$ can we say directly that $u(x)\leq G(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part 2 the exact equation to compare against is
$$
y'(x)=a(x)y(x)^2\implies \frac1{y(x)}=\frac1{y(0)}-\int_0^xa(s)ds,
\\
y(x)=\frac{y(0)}{1-y(0)A(x)}.
$$
By standard Grönwall philosophy, you could expect that if $u(0)\le y(0)$ then $u(x)\le y(x)$.

Going your way, you would again set $G(x)=\int_0^xa(s)y(s)^2ds$ and then consider
$$
\frac{G'(x)}{G(x)^2}\le\frac{a(x)u(x)^2}{u(x)^2}=a(x)
$$
and then integrate to get to the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much!